# Looping through column in a multidimensional array

Tags: arrays, vba

I have a multidimensional array with a layout as set out below:

```
Banana  10  20  30  40
Coconut 5   10  2   4
Apple   3   4   5   6
```

I want to loop through a specific column range in a worksheet to check if the values are either 'Banana', 'Coconut' or 'Apple'. When the cell value equate to a value in the first column of my array, I want to then output the array values next to that specific identifier. So for instance I want the output to be as below:

```
Shark
Banana  10  20  30  40
Pear
Apple   3   4   5   6
```

I understand that I need to loop through each cell in my range and then evaluate if the cell is equal to the values in the first column of the array. However, I am not sure how to do this. Typically I just use the setup below but I would like to understand how I can create a better solution in this case where I only want to loop through the first column in the array.

```
For Each cell In ws.Range("OUTPUT")
    For y = LBound(arr, 2) To UBound(arr, 2)
        If cell.Value = y Then
            For m = 1 To x
                ws.Cells(cell.Row, n + 1) = arr(n, m)
            Next m
            n = n + 1
        End If
    Next y
Next cell
```

Comment: Why not just use VLOOKUP or INDEX/MATCH formulae?

Comment: This solution is used to transfer data from one workbook to another so generic fomulas would not work in this instance.

Comment: Can you edit and post a print of your excel ?